# UIActivityViewController change position

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an UIActivityViewController like so:

```
let textToShare = "Swift is awesome!  Check out this website about it!"

        if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.codingexplorer.com/") {
            let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

            activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

            self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

How do I change the position?

Comment: Change position of what?

Comment: of the entire UIActivityViewController, right now it appears top left of the device screen, I would like the change that position

Comment: Sounds like it is showing from the position of the view which is presenting it. Can you try something like `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`. It is **not** a solution (!) but just to test it that works as intended.

Comment: I get an error ` Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'presen‌​tViewController'`